# Need Advice ( Javascript / dynamic CSS properties )

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my program, I have some links that go inline, across the top of the page.

[Link A,  Link B,  Link C, *etc...*]

The text is variable, so any time it is changed, the script checks the width to make sure it doesn't overflow out of the menu area, if it does then it will adjust the font size and padding.  The font size is also adjustable manually.

Everything is working fine, but I realized that as the font size changes, the text is no longer centered vertically.   The link menu is 60 pixels high, and the  tags display as blocks, with a padding to make the text display in the middle of the block.

I'm trying to figure out the math behind calculating the padding for the top and bottom of the links to center them no matter what font and size it is.
The closest I am getting is taking the height of the menu X = 60, the height of the text (I've been using the font size which seems more accurate than when I put the text in a span and measure the computed height of the span), lets say 20px, then I subtract the text height from the menu height, which leaves 40px for padding which I split in half, and have 20px on top and bottom of 20px font-size text.  This looks perfect, and it centers perfect.

Another example is 16px and 22px padding top and bottom, it works good, and appears to be centered in the menu.

font-size:16px  padding-top/padding-bottom:22px 
http://gyazo.com/7450c7db2887d731549c0edae5cb5c2b

**Now the problem:**

When the font size gets bigger, for example: 32px font size, padding top and bottom 14.  It seems like the top of the text starts at the same Y position as the smaller text, making it appear to align more to the bottom.

font-size:32px padding-top/padding-bottom:14px (32+14+14=60)
http://gyazo.com/513698b87fdc45498aea1bf6694ecefc

font-size:25px padding-top/padding-bottom:17.5px
*( more than two links not allowed )*
(This link was not allowed, but it starts showing quite a bit around font size 25 that its aligning more toward the bottom.

One other thing to keep in mind is the orange background is only 50px high, there's another 10px above it which is space for the mouse over display.

Does anyone have any ideas how to more accurately calculate the padding to show it centered vertically? I've been at this for hours and getting no where, where am I going wrong...? I really appreciate everyone who reads / comments.

Comment: have you tried setting the `line-height` to the same value as the `font-size`, that should vert align

Comment: It would help if you add minimal needed code to reproduce your scenario to the question itself..

Comment: adding a line height the same size of the text brought it up too high but adding a variable to account for the 10 pixels above the yellow menu space I think it works out.  Seems to align nicely, but I have to test it out a little more to be sure.  Thank you guys.  Sorry I didn't include some code, it's part of something pretty big..I was going to put together a small example but decided to just try and explain in detail plus include a couple screen shots.

Comment: Can you express your question in one sentence? Once you've done that, please use that for the title.